# Why is the value of the second object not changing?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript. And i am confused as how the below example is working? I have created an object `person` and i am assigning its value to `Person2.`

```
var person = "hello";  
var Person2 = person; 
person = "hey"; 

console.log(Person2); // prints hello
console.log(person); //prints hey
```

Why is the value of `Person2` not changing , even though `person` has been assigned a new value.?Is it because i am passing a reference. I am not clear with its implementation. What concept am i missing?

Comment: what's the problem? **Person2** prints hello because it is the value of **person** in the moment you assign it.

Comment: Note that your code `var person ="hello";` is not congruent with the statement "I have created an object `person`" . . . `person` is a primitive, specifically a string, therefore not an object . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with a `primitive` in JavaScript - a string is a primitive (so is a boolean, number, undefined and null). The primitives are assigned by value, not by reference.

Arrays and objects are assigned by reference.

```
var person = ['test'];
var person2 = person;
person[0] = 'hi';

console.log(person); //['hi'];
console.log(person2); //['hi'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's step through what's happening in your code...

```
1: var person = "hello";  
2: var Person2 = person; 
3: person = "hey"; 
4: console.log(Person2);
5: console.log(person);
```

1. person is assigned the reference to the new string object "hello".
2. Person2 is assigned by reference the existing string "hello".
3. person is assigned the reference to the new string object "hey".
4. Person2 is pointing to the "hello" string so this is output
5. person is pointing to the "hey" string so this is output

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are **not** passing a reference (at least, not one that points to `person`)

You haven't changed the value of `Person2` so the value remains `"hello"` which is the only value you have assigned to it.

Comment: While true, this answer doesn't clarify the difference between how JavaScript assigns values of primitives and objects, which is what the real answer is.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of person2 to the value of person, then you are changing the value of person afterward. The value of person2 will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Strings and numbers (primitives) are NOT passed by reference, this is only the case with objects or array (arrays are objects strictly). So assigning it to a new variable COPIES the string.

To pass it by reference you would use something like

```
var person = {message: "hello"};
var Person2 = person;
person.message = "Hey";

person === Person2 // true
```